# Checkbox set value from DB

Tags: php, codeigniter

So the scenario is this:
I currently have a DB with TV Shows with RSS Feeds. 
The feeds (TV Shows) table has ID, name, network, feed, active.
I have setup a field in the accounts table called favourites, i thought comma delimited ID's of the TV Shows might be a good idea, but im not sure anymore.

I am currently looking to implement a controller in CI that will look at the DB in the favourites field, for eg if it was filled with 104,149,150

How can I get those ID's to transfer into the view so I can set the values to the respective Show's?

```
    <?php foreach ($shows as $show) { ?>

             <div class="grid_1">
              <?  $data = array(
    'name'        => $show['name'],
    'id'          => $show['id'],
    'value'       => $show['name'],
    'checked'     => FALSE,
    );

echo form_checkbox($data); ?>

            </div>

            <div class="item"><?=form_label($show['name']);?></div>

                       <?php } ?>
```

The view currently outputs the TV shows in the database with a check box next to each show, what is the best way for me to set user preferences for favourites? So that I can set the values of each checkbox according to the user preference

I hope I have explained what I am trying to do well,

Thanks!

Comment: *"i thought comma delimited..."*. Let me stop you right there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load a view and send variables/parameters to it as such:

```
$params['data'] = array(1 => 'hello');
$this->load->view('path/view.php', $params);
```

**EDIT:**
To save favorites, I suggest creating a new table ('favorites') that contains a favorite_id, user_id, show_id .. perhaps a date added, maybe some other things.

In the Shows page, where the checkboxes reside, you could do the following:

```
<input type="checkbox" <?=(in_array(SHOW_ID, $favorites) ? 'checked' : null);?> />
```

This means you must send over an array called `$favorites` which would look something like `$params['favorites']` in your controller.

The query to get the favorites would look something like this:

```
$q = $this->db->query('SELECT show_id FROM favorites WHERE user_id=?', array($user_id));
$params['favorites'] = $q->result_array();
```

The `array($user_id)` following the query is called query binding, used for security.

Comment: Not sure how to match that with id from DB to each checkbox.

Comment: When you loop through all the available shows (hopefully you have a SHOW_ID of some sort), you can see if the SHOW_ID matches any of the shows the user has in his favorites. If $favorites = array(10,15,20), then a value of 'checked' will echo (<?= is the same as <? echo) in that line and your checkbox will appear as CHECKED.

Comment: Yes I have show id. Thanks I think I get it. I will try it soon. While im here how would I approach updating favourites? Would I have to update every row that matched the user id. If we are using the array to check then why not have a comma delimited format in one field?

Comment: It will be much easier in the long run.. if a user has 50 favorites, it will be much simpler to find a certain fav in the database than have to traverse arrays, etc. Having sql do the logic will be faster than php in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Mike is right, here is an example using CI :)

[Clicky](http://codepad.org/PM5Lf9M1)